# Bytecode and Objects

Tags: java, bytecode, verification, instrumentation

I am working on a bytecode instrumentation project. Currently when handling objects, the verifier throws an error most of the time. So I would like to get things clear concerning rules with objects (I read the JVMS but couldn't find the answer I was looking for):

I am instrumenting the NEW instruction:

original bytecode

```
NEW <MyClass>
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL <MyClass.<init>>
```

after instrumentation

```
NEW <MyClass>
DUP
INVOKESTATIC <Profiler.handleNEW>
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL <MyClass.<init>>
```

Note that I added a call to Profiler.handleNEW() which takes as argument an object reference (the newly created object).

The piece of code above throws a VerificationError. While if I don't add the INVOKESTATIC (leaving only the DUP), it doesn't. So what is the rule that I'm violating? I can duplicate an uninitialized reference but I can't pass it as parameter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: You should definitely not be passing any object instances as parameters until their constructors are complete, whether the Verifier allows you or not.

Comment: Even if I won't manipulate the object just store its reference?

Comment: @HH yes, see here:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=13894854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM verifier treats an object whose constructor has yet to be called as if it had a special compile-time type called "uninitialized".

So what's happening from the verifier's point of view is that you are passing the wrong type of object as the first parameter to `Profiler.handleNEW()`, because "uninitialized" is not considered a subclass of Object (so to speak).

The relevant part of the JVM spec regarding how "uninitialized" is defined is [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#9839).

Answer (score 1):

Until the `java.lang.Object` constructor is called (technically it is probably normally exited), the type of the reference is "uninitialised". So you can't do much with the reference before calling a constructor on it. This is also true in the constructors of the object in question.